# Let $M$ and $A$ be matrices for which the product matrix $MA$ is defined.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ and $A$ be matrices for which the product matrix $MA$ is defined. If the jth column of $A$ is a linear combination of a set of columns of $A$, prove that the jth column of $MA$ is a linear combination of the corresponding columns of $MA$ with the same corresponding coefficients.

I am unsure of where to start or, quite honestly, what the question is asking. I have spent some time wrestling with this in my head and I am not developing any intuition. Thanks for your help!

My solution given your comments is now

Assume we have matrices $A$ and $M$ where the product $MA$ is defined and that the jth column of $A$ is a linear combination of some set of columns of $A$. Consider the jth column of $A$
                    $A_j=
      \begin{pmatrix}
       a_1 \\
       a_2\\
       \vdots\\
       a_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     =a_iA_i+a_kA_k+ \dots +a_lA_l
     =
      a_i\begin{pmatrix}
       i_1 \\
       i_2\\
       \vdots\\
       i_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     +
      a_k\begin{pmatrix}
       k_1 \\
       k_2\\
       \vdots\\
       k_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     + \dots +
      a_l\begin{pmatrix}
       l_1 \\
       l_2\\
       \vdots\\
       l_n
      \end{pmatrix}$

If we consider the jth row of $M$ since the jth column of $MA$ will be the product of the $jth$ row of $M$ and the $jth$ column of $A$ we have
                    $M_j=
      \begin{pmatrix}
       b_1 & b_2 & \dots & b_n
      \end{pmatrix}$
                We have
                    $(MA)_j=
      \begin{pmatrix}
       b_1a_1 \\
       b_2a_2\\
       \vdots\\
       b_na_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     =
      a_i\begin{pmatrix}
       b_1i_1 \\
       b_2i_2\\
       \vdots\\
       b_ni_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     +
      a_k\begin{pmatrix}
       b_1k_1 \\
       b_2k_2\\
       \vdots\\
       b_nk_n
      \end{pmatrix}
     + \dots +
      a_l\begin{pmatrix}
       b_1l_1 \\
       b_2l_2\\
       \vdots\\
       b_nl_n
      \end{pmatrix}$

and so $MA_j$ is a linear combination of the corresponding columns of $MA$.

Comment: Perhaps it'd help to represent $A$ as $\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n}$ where $a_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$.  Then $MA = \pmatrix{Ma_1 & Ma_2 & \cdots & Ma_n}$.  Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: I might see where that might help me. Where I am really baffled is in saying the jth column of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$....?

Comment: Suppose the fifth column of $ A $ is $ A_5$ and $ A_5 = 3A_2 + 4 A_3$. What's the fifth column of $ MA $? It's $ M A_5$. And what's that equal to?

Comment: Right, okay. Is a little clearer. So, is it a fixed set, say $A_2$ and $A_3$ in your example for each column or does the set change from column to column?

Comment: Just set $a_k$ (an arbitrary $k$th column) equal to $\alpha a_i + \cdots + \omega a_j$ (a linear combination of arbitrary columns $\{a_i, \dots, a_j\}$).  Then you just need to prove that $Ma_k$ is a linear combination of $\{Ma_i, \dots, Ma_j\}$.

Comment: The question only tells us that one particular column of $ A$ , the $ j $ th column, is a linear combination of other columns of $ A $.

Comment: I'm going to work on this for a bit and post a solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kicker is that if we write $A$ in terms of its columns as $A=(A_1\:A_2\cdots A_n),$ then you can prove that $$MA=(MA_1\:MA_2\cdots MA_n).$$ So, in general, the $k$th column of $MA$ is $M$ times the $k$th column of $A$. Multiplying on the left by $M$ in the linear combination equation will get us the rest of the way.